# What are "Included Services" in a Service useful for?

Tags: service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a custom profile for a proprietary device (my smartphone app will be the only thing communicating with my peripheral) that includes two simple services.  Each service allows the client to read and write a single byte of data on the peripheral.  I would like to add the ability to read and write both bytes in a single transaction.

I tried adding a third service that simply included the two existing single byte services but all that appears to do is assign a UUID that combines the UUIDs for the existing services and I don't see how to use the combined UUID since it doesn't have any Characteristic Values.

The alternatives I'm considering are to make a separate service for the two bytes and combine their effects on my server, or I could replace all of this with a single service that includes the two bytes along with a boolean flag for each byte that indicates whether or not the associated byte should be written.

The first alternative seems overly complicated and the second would preclude individual control of notifications and indications for the separate bytes.

Is there a way to use included services to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite an old question, but in case anyone else comes across it I leave a comment here.

Here are two parts. One is a late answer for Lance F: You had a wrong  understanding of the BLE design principles. Services are defined on the host level of the BLE stack. And you considered your problem from the application level point view, wanting an atomic transaction to provide you with a compound object of two distinct entities. Otherwise why would you have defined two services?

The second part is an answer to the actual question taken as quote from "Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy" by Kevin Townsend et al., O'Reilly, 2014, p.58:
Included services can help avoid duplicating data in a GATT server. If a service will be referenced by other services, you can use this mechanism to save memory and simplify the layout of the GATT server. In the previous analogy with classes and objects, you could see include definitions as pointers or references to an existing object instance.

It's an update of my answer to clarify why there is no need for the included services in a problem stated by Lance F.

I am mostly familiar with BLE use in medical devices, so I briefly sketch the SIG defined Glucose Profile as an example to draw some analogies with your problem.

Let's imagine a server device which has the Glucose Service with 2 defined characteristics: Glucose Measurement and Glucose Measurement Context. A client can subscribe for notifications of either or both of these characteristics. In some time later the client device can change its subscriptions by simply writing to the Client Configuration Characteristic Descriptor of the corresponding characteristic.

Server also has a special mandatory characteristic - Record Access Control Point (RACP), which is used by a client to retrieve or update glucose measurement history.

If a client wants to get a number of stored history records it writes to the RACP { OpCode: 4 (Report number of stored records), Operator: 1 (All records) }. Then a server sends an indication from the RACP { OpCode: 5 (Number of stored records response), Operator: 0 (Null), Operand: 17 (some number) }.

If a client wants to get any specific records it writes to the RACP  { OpCode: 1 (Report stored records), Operator: 4 (Within range of, inclusive), Operand: [13, 14] (for example the records 13 and 14) }. In response a server sends requested records one by one as notifications of the Glucose Measurement and Glucose Measurement Context characteristics, and then sends an indication from the RACP characteristic to report a status of the operation.

So Glucose Measurement and Glucose Measurement Context are your Mode and Rate characteristics, then you also need one more control characteristic - an analog of the RACP. Now you need to define a number of codes, operators, and operands. Create a structure whichever suits you best, for example, Code: 1 - update, Operator: 1 - Mode only, Operand: actual number. A client writes it to the control point characteristic. A server gets notified on write, interprets it, and acts in a way defined by your custom profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm having a hard time understanding your answer WRT part 1. I provided two services for two reasons: 1) I need the ability to change either local variable in the server without affecting the other, 2) I want to be able to allow Notification for local changes to either local variable  independently.  I think that pretty much dictates a separate service for each of the two local variables.  And you're correct that my desire for a means of writing to both Characteristics in a single transaction stems from the need to update both from the client atomically on occasion.

Comment: WRT part 2, your answer does clarify my confusion over the intended use of Included Services.  I ended up creating a 3rd Service that writes (or reads) both local variables.  Seems cumbersome but it accomplished what I needed.  Can you suggest a better alternative?

Comment: You define a service for conceptually similar things. There is no need to define two services if they are only about switching on/off notifications or indications. You got client configuration characteristic descriptors for that purpose to un/subscribe for notifications/indications of a particular characteristic.

Comment: Also I am a bit confused when interpreting your original question and reply. The former mentions reading and writing operations which I would use for some functional control points characteristics on a server side. And the latter says about notifications that corresponds to a server sending periodically one way information about an already accomplished fact. I try my best to suggest you a better solution but I would really need to hear more details about your project.

Comment: Here's some details:

Comment: The product has 2 local "control" variables Mode and Rate each of which has it's own service with read, write, and Notification capabilities.  It's important to be able to write either one without disturbing the other and it's desirable to enable Notification on each one individually.  In addition to all of that, in certain use cases it's necessary to write both at the same time with no chance that only one of the pair gets updated before the connection is lost.  Given those requirements  a separate service was needed for each plus an additional service combining the two.

Comment: Because having three services for two related but somewhat independent Characteristics seems redundant and a bit cumbersome (I had to ensure that writes to one service updated the GATT DB for another) I was looking for a more elegant option.

Comment: I have updated my original answer to have a better text alignment. Hope it helps